# How to install libelfg0-dev on ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit version

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, tee

I am trying to setup Open-TEE environment by following the instruction from https://open-tee.github.io/documentation/

The Open-TEE requires installing libelfg0-dev. But when I run

```
sudo apt-get install libelfg0-dev
```

I got following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libelfg0-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libelfg0-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I checked the packages I installed on Ubuntu by using

```
dpkg -l | grep libelf
```

The result is :

```
ii  libelf1:amd64    0.165-3ubuntu1    amd64    library to read and write ELF files
ii  libelf1:i386     0.165-3ubuntu1    i386     library to read and write ELF files
```

So I think the package is not on my Ubuntu yet.

Anyone knows how to install the package libelfg0?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Install libelf-dev instead of libelfg0-dev if using Ubuntu 16.04LTS:

```
sudo apt-get install libelf-dev
```

I reported the issue to Open-TEE here:

- https://github.com/Open-TEE/project/issues/23